# How to code Nested Loop with synchronous in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift3, nested-loops

In my project, I call getMain() and that has nested loop. That loop call setUp(). My problem is setUp() before finish, upper loop is quit.

Firstly call getMian():

```
func getMain(){

    let entityDescription = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "MainThemeHome")
    do{
        let results = try context.fetch(entityDescription)

        if(results.count) > 0 {

            sections.removeAll()
            debugPrint(results.count)
            outer_count = results.count

                for i in 0 ..< (results.count){


                        let match = results[i] as! NSManagedObject

                        let associated_url = match.value(forKey: "main_associated_url") as! String

                        let name = match.value(forKey: "main_name") as! String

                       //call function
                             self.setUpViews(associated_url: associated_url, main_name: name, i: i )
                                                   self.myGroup.leave()


                }

                       }else{

        }

    }catch{}


}
```

Loop call setUp() is below,

```
  private func setUp(associated_url : String , main_name: String,i : Int) {

        if Reachability().isInternetAvailable() == true {

            self.rest.auth(auth: self.prefs.value(forKey: "access_token") as! String!)
            self.rest.get(url: StringResource().mainURL + associated_url ,  parma: [ "show_min": "true" ], finished: {(result : NSDictionary, status : Int) -> Void in

                self.assetsTable.removeAll()
                if(status == 200){
                    let data = result["data"] as! NSArray

                        for item in 0…data.count - 1 {



                            let themes : AnyObject = data[item] as AnyObject
                            let created = themes["created"] as! String
                            let assets_id = themes["id"] as! Int
                            let name = themes["name"] as! String
                            var poster_img_url = themes["poster_image_url"] as! String
                            let provider_id = themes["provider_id"] as! Int

                            poster_img_url = StringResource().posterURL + poster_img_url


                            self.assetsTable.append(AssetsTableItem(created: created, assets_id: assets_id, name: name, poster_image_url: poster_img_url , provider_id: provider_id))

                        }

      }


                    self.sections.append(SectionsHome(package_name: main_name, package_url: associated_url,i: i,packageTable: self.assetsTable))
                    self.inner_count = self.sections.count


                }else{


                }
            })
    }
    }
```

How to control setUp() is completely finished, loop will be increase count and quit. How to solve this problem. Please help.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? Which loop exits and what you want to aceive.

Comment: First, don't use if..else, use guard let to better code. and second, use GCD while calling setUp() to async code & UI.

Comment: @KrishnaKumar In setUp() get data from Server and store data in sections. In getMain() looping is finished but setUp retrieving and saving are not finished yet  that time getMain() loop is quit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use closures in setUp function so that when the setUp if finished you will get the callback

```
 private func setUp(associated_url : String , main_name: String,i : Int, ,sucess:((Void) -> Void)?,failure:((Void?) -> Void)?) {

        if Reachability().isInternetAvailable() == true {

            self.rest.auth(auth: self.prefs.value(forKey: "access_token") as! String!)
            self.rest.get(url: StringResource().mainURL + associated_url ,  parma: [ "show_min": "true" ], finished: {(result : NSDictionary, status : Int) -> Void in

                self.assetsTable.removeAll()
                if(status == 200){
                    let data = result["data"] as! NSArray

                        for item in 0…data.count - 1 {



                            let themes : AnyObject = data[item] as AnyObject
                            let created = themes["created"] as! String
                            let assets_id = themes["id"] as! Int
                            let name = themes["name"] as! String
                            var poster_img_url = themes["poster_image_url"] as! String
                            let provider_id = themes["provider_id"] as! Int

                            poster_img_url = StringResource().posterURL + poster_img_url


                            self.assetsTable.append(AssetsTableItem(created: created, assets_id: assets_id, name: name, poster_image_url: poster_img_url , provider_id: provider_id))

                        }

      }


                    self.sections.append(SectionsHome(package_name: main_name, package_url: associated_url,i: i,packageTable: self.assetsTable))
                    self.inner_count = self.sections.count
                sucess!()

                }else{
             failure!()

                }
            })
    }
    }
```

And change the way you call the function as

```
    self.setUp(associated_url: associated_url, main_name: name, i: i, sucess: { () in
     debugPrint("SUCCESS")
}) { () in
    debugPrint("FAILURE")
    }
```

Comment: I changed but ("Extra argument 'success" in call ) error happen.

Comment: Ok I will check and will get back to you soon

Comment: The way I call setUp() function

Comment: remove the extra coma "," n front of sucess.

Comment: self.setUp(associated_url: associated_url, main_name: name, i: i , sucess: {() in 
 debugPrint("SUCCESS")
      },failure:{ () in
          debugPrint("FAILURE")
})

Comment: self.setUp(associated_url: associated_url, main_name: name, i: i, sucess: { () in
                                debugPrint("SUCCESS")
                            }){ () in
                                debugPrint("FAILURE")
                            } as! ((Void?) -> Void)

Comment: My code inform need (as! (Void?) -> Void)  added but didn't solve.

Comment: Could you try modifying the setUp func declaration as
   private func setUp(associated_url : String , main_name: String,i : Int,sucess:((Void) -> Void)?,failure:((Void) -> Void)?) {

}

Comment: Now, My code is clean error but the problem didn't solve yet.
The outer loop has (8) count but My Inner Loop only get (6) times . That's mean Inner Loop didn't complete , the outer loop is quite. I'm afraid of you. Thanks for your answer bro. I think I need to try another solution.

Comment: Where are you calling self.myGroup.leave() ? function

Comment: I deleted it bro

Comment: Why ?? Try calling that function inside the sucess block
self.setUp(associated_url: associated_url, main_name: name, i: i, sucess: { () in
  self.myGroup.leave() 
}) { () in
    debugPrint("FAILURE")
    }

Answer (score 0):

What I can understand is that you want to make loop wait until the data is not fetched in that particular interation number. If this is the case then you should look for synchronous operation. Like dont let the control passed to next iteration until the operation is finished. But this is a bad practice and makes your app behaviour non responsive.

I would say to work on asynchronous line and create a block or closure and put your code what is expected to perform when you receive your data and put the code outside that block that are not dependent on the data. Blocks anyway capture the environment in that case you should not be worried about the control getting passed.